# How to access $rootScope in view (cshtml)

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code

```
...
...
...
if (response.data) {
    console.log("response data was not null");
    if (response.data != null) {
        $rootScope.permissions = response.data.permissions;
        console.log("permissions: ", $rootScope.permissions);
        localStorage.setItem("UserPermissions", JSON.stringify($rootScope.permissions));        
...
...
...
```

and I want to hide the `<li>` tab(s) based on the permissions. I have tried multiple things but have not been able to find a solution. 
Reading online on how to use rootScope, I came across posts which had a solution with using `$root` but that did not work either.

```
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="text-align: center;">
    <ul class="header-menu">
        <li ng-if="$root.permissions[1].includes('permissionName')"><a ng-class="{ activeMenuItem: isActive('/Cases')}" ui-sref="Caes" class="current">My Cases<span class="count-wrap" ng-show="getCases() > 0" ng-bind="getCaseCount()" ng-cloak></span></a></li>
        <li ng-if="permissions[1].includes('permissionName')"><a ng-class="{ activeMenuItem: isActive('/Lawyers')}" ui-sref="Lawyers" class="current">My Lawyers<span class="count-wrap" ng-show="Law.Lawyer > 0" ng-bind="Law.LawyerCount" ng-cloak></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Its a little hard to create a snippet but I am looking for guidance if there is better way to do this or if I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify $rootScope in ypur view. 
You can use it the same way as you use $scope variables.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
    //set permissions to rootScope
    $rootScope.permissions=[{name:"permission 1",isActive:true},{name:"permission 2",isActive:false}]

});
```

```html
 
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="text-align: center;">
  <ul class="header-menu">
   <li ng-repeat="permission in permissions">
   <a ng-if="permission.isActive">{{permission.name}} is Active<span class="count-wrap" ng-show="getCases() > 0" ng-bind="getCaseCount()" ng-cloak></span></a>
   <a  ng-if="!permission.isActive">{{permission.name}} is Not Active<span class="count-wrap" ng-show="getCases() > 0" ng-bind="getCaseCount()" ng-cloak></span></a>
   </li>   
  </ul>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When faced to this in an app, and also for value to be updated in the view i used a getter function to get `$rootScope` values in the controller (i took the habit to name my controllers but if you don't, just remove `ctrl.`):

In the view:

```
<li ng-if="ctrl.getPermissions()[1].includes('permissionName')">...
```

In the controller function:

```
function ctrlFunc($rootScope) {
    this.getPermissions = function(){ //or whatever way you use to define your functions, with $scope or this
        return $rootScope.permissions;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ng-if="::$root.permissions.length > 1 && ::$root.permissions[1].includes('permissionName')"
```